# Classical (or less classical) examples of posets with incomparable elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As classic examples of ordering relations for wich there are incomparable elements, I could give :

- the divisibility relation amongst integers : 5 and 7 are incomparable as to divisibility
- set inclusion : {a, b, c} and   {a, b, d} are incomparable as to inclusion ( though they are not disjoint).

I think these two examples are the most common.

What other examples ( still classic, but more original) could be given?

Comment: Real valued functions on any set by pointwise order. Any two functions that satisfy opposite inequalities at different points are incomparable. See also [Riesz spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space). Symmetric or Hermitian matrices by positive definiteness, if $A-B$ is indefinite they are incomparable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you're right. But if you consider lattices, a lattice is distributive if and only if it does not contain the diamond and the pentagon lattice as a sub-lattice. These two lattices are given by posets with incomparable elements. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice